# Insert multiple based on select

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query

```
INSERT INTO page_role (page_id, role_id)
SELECT 
  (SELECT id FROM pages WHERE name = 'masterdata'),
  (SELECT id FROM roles WHERE name = 'PropertyOwner')
```

But I have the error :

> Subquery return more than 1 row

How I can handle that ?

This select returning one result :

```
SELECT id 
FROM pages 
WHERE name = 'masterdata'
```

but this one

```
SELECT id 
FROM roles 
WHERE name = 'PropertyOwner'
```

more than one.

Modified query :

```
INSERT INTO page_role (page_id, role_id)
SELECT 45, id FROM roles r
 INNER JOIN page_role pr ON r.id = pr.role_id 
 WHERE r.name = 'PropertyOwner' AND pr.page_id <> 45
```

Error message : `Duplicate entry 45-18223 for key page_role PRIMARY`

Comment: So which row from `Roles` *joins* with the row from `pages`

Comment: @EdGzi no because I should ignore inserts that already exists

Comment: @klsdskldsd I see. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `IGNORE`.

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO page_role (page_id, role_id)
SELECT 45, id FROM roles r
 INNER JOIN page_role pr ON r.id = pr.role_id 
 WHERE r.name = 'PropertyOwner' AND pr.page_id <> 45
```

Comment: I will have duplications, isn't it ?

Comment: No, it will ignore the duplicated record. See here https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-insert-ignore/  "MySQL returned a message indicating that one row was inserted and the other row was ignored."